# Excel Function To Pull Specifically Order Information from String

Tags: excel

another user of Stack Overflow kindly provided this function to use:

```
=MID(B5,FIND("¬",SUBSTITUTE(B5,"-","¬",3))+1,FIND("¬",SUBSTITUTE(B5,"-","¬",4))-FIND("¬",SUBSTITUTE(B5,"-","¬",3))-1)
```

It was meant to pull a specific 4-5 letter code out of a longer code formatted like this:

```
P-APPLE-3N-A4XM-A2
where: APPLE can vary in length and characters
Where: A4XM can vary in length and characters
And Where: A2 can vary in length and characters
P, 3N will almost always be the same.
```

Recently I decided to include the -A2 in the info that I want to pull, but I am having a hard time understanding the function that the user provided. Can anyone provide input into how to modify this code to include all information after the 2nd dash.

There will always be the same number of dashes.

Comment: Update your code with example of what you want out of function that runs on your example text. If you have multiple examples, even better. If you have sample code you tried, it becomes an excellent question showing effort

Comment: like: `=MID(B5,FIND("¬",SUBSTITUTE(B5,"-","¬",3))+1,LEN(B5))`???

Comment: did he not provide 3 different formulas to extract those 3 different codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @Dirk Reichel

```
=MID(B5,FIND("¬",SUBSTITUTE(B5,"-","¬",3))+1,LEN(B5))
```

This is a much more understandable formula too. The last one I had was just confusing beyond words.

Thank you